# Sabre Steps to Update a PNR with involuntary change

Tags: sabre

What are the steps to accept an involuntary change in a Sabre PNR using SOAP airlines methods?

I'm looking to delete WK status segments and confirm the SC segments to confirm the involuntary change on the itinerary.

Thanks